# Using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ prove this function is continuous

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=x^3+3x-1$.  at $x=2 $

A understanding that I need to ensure that when $\epsilon >0$, $\delta >0$ such that

$|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<|x-c|<\delta$ Where l=limit, c=constant.

Am failing to understand what values to plug into the definition to show proof.

Help me.

Comment: If it is going to be continuous, then $l$ must be $f(2)$ and $c$ must be $2$. The hard part will be coming up with a $\delta$ for any $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

How to show that a function is continuous on its whole domain (I misread the question at first):

Let $ a \in \mathbb{R}$ be given. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.
Select $\delta > 0$, $\delta=\min\{1, \dfrac{\varepsilon}{((|a|+1)^2 + |a|(|a|+1) + |a|^2+3)}\},$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x-a|<\delta$,
$$|f(x) - f(a)| = |x^3 + 3x -1 - a^3 - 3a + 1 | = |x^3 - a^3 + 3x - 3a| \leq | x^3 - a^3| + 3|x-a|$$ 
$$  = |x-a|(|x^2 + ax+a^2| + 3) \leq |x-a|(|x|^2 +|a||x| + |a|^2 + 3) < |x-a|\cdot ((|a|+\delta)^2 + |a|(|a|+\delta) + |a|^2+3) < |x-a|\cdot ((|a|+1)^2 + |a|(|a|+1) + |a|^2+3)<  ((|a|+1)^2 + |a|(|a|+1) + |a|^2+3)\delta = C(a)\delta \leq \frac{C(a)\varepsilon}{C(a)}=   \varepsilon$$
Since $\varepsilon >0$ was given arbitrarily, $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$. Since $a \in \mathbb{R}$ was given arbitrarily, $f(x)$ is continuous

Answer (score 1):

Well, finding out values to plug is the tricky part. It might be helpful to work out expression for $f(2 + \delta) - f(2)$ and try to find a crude, easy to work with bound:

$$
f(2+\delta) - f(2) = (2+\delta)^3+3(2+\delta)-1 - 13 = \delta^3 + 6\delta^2 + 15\delta
$$

For $\delta < 1$, then
$$
\left|f(2+\delta) - f(2)\right|\leq 22\delta
$$

All we have to do now is to pick for each $\varepsilon$ a $\delta$ such that the above is less than $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove that $f$ is continuous at $2$ we have to look at the difference
$$f(x)-f(2)=(x^3+3x-1)-13=x^3+3x-14=(x-2)(x^2+2x+7)\ ,\tag{1}$$
and we have to prove that $|f(x)-f(2)|<\epsilon$ when $x$ is sufficiently near $2$. The factor $(x-2)$ on the right hand side of $(1)$ certainly helps, but we need an additional trick, as follows: We consider only points $x$ which are at distance $\leq1$ from $2$ to begin with. For such $x$ we obviously have
$$|x^2+2x+7|\leq3^2+2\cdot 3+7=22$$
and therefore
$$|f(x)-f(2)|\leq 22\ |x-2|\ .\tag{2}$$
Given an $\epsilon>0$ we now put $\delta:=\min\bigl\{{\epsilon\over22},1\bigr\}>0$. When $|x-2|<\delta$ then the "technical assumption" $|x-2|\leq1$ used in $(2)$ is fulfilled, and we have
$$|f(x)-f(2)|<22\delta\leq\epsilon\ ,$$
as required.